# Camel route with two MQs in it

Tags: apache-camel

I have a flow that I've defined using camel but I ended up using 6+ routes to accomplish what I wanted. Is there a way to do this with one or fewer than 4 routes?

I've outlined the routes below. The first one reads a message (containing an ID) from MQ1 and produces N-messages (expected to be in thousands) in MQ2 based on what it finds in a database for that one ID (db is not shown here). The messages produced in MQ2 have a type field defined, and based on that the choice element filters the messages to put them in the right MQ. Then each MQ(3,4,5) is processed by it's own processor (ProcessorMQ3,4,5). Once that's done, they output the result of the processing to MQ6 and ProcessorMQ6 reads the result and updates the database (also not shown).

Route 1: [Start]--->[MQ1]--->[ProcessorMQ1]--->[MQ2]

Route 2: [MQ2]--->[Choice]--->[MQ3,MQ4,MQ5 based on header value]

Route 3: [MQ3]--->[ProcessorMQ3]--->[MQ6]

Route 4: [MQ4]--->[ProcessorMQ4]--->[MQ6]

Route 5: [MQ5]--->[ProcessorMQ5]--->[MQ6]

Route 6: [MQ6]--->[ProcessorMQ6]--->[End]

Is there a way to do this using one route or am I doing this correctly? I will need to introduce 10 more "types" so the range MQ3-5 will increase by 10.

Comment: This looks fine, no problem. Depending on error/tx handling semantics and performance requirements you could replace MQ3-5 with `direct`, but in general sending it off to a queue is better.

Comment: What does direct do? How would it be used if I were to replace MQ3-5 with direct? Is it like an endpoint that I can share between routes?

Comment: Yes. It is a synchronous call (using the same thread) to another route in the same `CamelContext`. It really depends on your requirements if that is better here (normally it is not)

Comment: There's a question of whether you CAN make it one route and whether you SHOULD. It sounds like you don't think you can, Why? Could you explain that. For instance, putting the [Choice] after ProcessorMQ1, and routing to ProcessorMQ3, 4, 5... etc. Once you know that you can, you can evaluate the pros and cons between the two options: single or multiple.

Comment: You are correct, there are two questions here; Can I merge these routes and should I merge these routes. I don't know the answer to either of those questions.

Comment: If I put Choice after ProcessorMQ1, it would filter the original message in the MQ1, which just contains the ID. ProcessMQ1 reads that ID, accesses a database and produces multiple messages in MQ2. So I would need to write all those messages somehow in the exchange.getOut() so that Choice can filter each message individually, right? Then choice can forward it to ProcessorMQ3-5 but can I put it in an MQ too in case ProcessorMQ3-5 crap out?

Comment: Yeah, I think you mostly answered your question: you can MQ3,4,5,6 can be made into a single route, but having the queues gives you some options on "crap out". ProcessorMQ1 is a "splitter" EIP. (it would be similar to reading a file, and using a splitter to send messages that are individual lines). But, once again, you can use a Queue there for similar reasons as the others. 
I think its a design decision based on the complexity and probability of failure of the processing.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, your route design looks better now. Why do you want to minimise ? It will complicate your exception handling at the least.

I would always prefer to create micro routes which are functionally independent to each other, that way its makes life easier to write exception handling & unit test cases in a better way. (Even it is very good for refactoring, in the future if you want to move these routes to its own unit of deployment)

Yes, you are doing it  in a correct way !

Cheers

Comment: The team lead says that I should be able to do it with one route but then he said to get the first few integration routes going however I wanted so we can refactor later. Having this as a single route would be easier to manage I guess, but I don't think it's possible.

Comment: Yeah, not a bad approach . Also it's not going to be tough to have your kind of design straight away. Anyways it depends on any other challenges you have :) Good luck